# How to resolve "TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256." error?

Tags: solidity, remix

Am currently working on my dApp and am facing some errors in the code, aiming to retrieve data.

Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

contract AttendanceSystemContract {
    // Attendance Class
    struct Attendance {
        uint attendanceID;
        address employeeAddressID;
        string employeeName;
        string checkinDate;
        string checkinTime;
        string checkoutDate;
        string checkoutTime;
        string workChoice;
    }

    // Mapping
    mapping (uint => Attendance) public attendanceList;
    uint public attendanceCount;

    // Functions
    // Taking Attendance for Clocking In
    function takeAttendance (address _employeeAddressID, string memory _employeeName, string memory _checkinDate, string memory _checkinTime, string memory _checkoutDate, string memory _checkoutTime, string memory _workChoice) public {
        attendanceCount++;
        attendanceList[attendanceCount] = Attendance(attendanceCount, _employeeAddressID, _employeeName, _checkinDate, _checkinTime, _checkoutDate, _checkoutTime,  _workChoice);
    }

    // Updating Attendance for Clocking Out
    function updateAttendance (uint _attendanceID, string memory _checkoutDate, string memory _checkoutTime) public {
        Attendance memory attendanceObject = attendanceList[_attendanceID];
        attendanceObject.checkoutDate = _checkoutDate;
        attendanceObject.checkoutTime = _checkoutTime;
        attendanceList[_attendanceID] = attendanceObject;
    }

    // Retrieving Attendance Records for Individual Wallet ID
    function retrieveAttendance(address _employeeAddressID) public view returns (uint, address, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory) {
        return (attendanceList[_employeeAddressID].attendanceID, attendanceList[_employeeAddressID].employeeAddressID, attendanceList[_employeeAddressID].employeeName, attendanceList[_employeeAddressID].checkinDate, attendanceList[_employeeAddressID].checkinTime, attendanceList[_employeeAddressID].checkoutDate, attendanceList[_employeeAddressID].checkoutTime, attendanceList[_employeeAddressID].workChoice);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `retrieveAttendance` you are passing parameter `address _employeeAddressID` instead of `uint _attendanceID`. You need to change that and to use `_attendanceID` as index of the array, not `_employeeAddressID`.

Comment: Thank you. It actually works!

However, how do I make it such that I want to retrieve the items in the array by using the parameter `address _employeeAddressID` as index instead of `uint _attendanceID`?

Comment: You need another structure. Or you can use it by the beginning, getting rid of `_attendanceID`, using something like `mapping (addess => Attendance) public attendanceList;` and updating `takeAttendance` and `updateAttendance` to use `_employeeAddressID` as index.

Comment: Also, `updateAttendance` method can be simplified (from 4 lines to 2 lines). Can you figure out how? ;)